# Datebox plugin remove the closebutton

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

i am using the Datebox plugin for jquerymobile from [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/), also to note is that i am using the timeflipbox mode. 
My question is, is there a away to remove the close Button( [X] ) on the top left corner of the Timeflipbox or the Timebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demeter's answer is good for the Bootstrap version of DateBox. For the jQuery Mobile version, the CSS selector shouldbe

```
.ui-datebox-container > a.ui-btn {
    display: none;
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/vKwAdr)**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by using css. Just add display:none to the specified class.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .closer.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove.pull-left{display:none!important}
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me :(. I would give you a fiddle but there is no https cdn link for the datebox.js link..